# Python: giving answer according to given arguments

Tags: python, arguments, default

Could somebody help me?

I need to define a function where the user gives 2 arguments, but all are already defined.
If the user gives 1 argument, the program squares it. If the user gives 2, you multiply them. If none are given, the program returns 'none'.

My solution:

```
def area(a=1,b=1):
  if not a or b:
    return 'none' 
  elif not b:
    return a**2
  else:
    return a*b
```

But that doesn't work somehow. Help please?
ps. Sorry for the layout, I'm new to this site

Comment: You are setting both `a` and `b` to always have a value of one. change them to zero. However the only way to have `b` and not `a` is to set `a` to 0 when you call the function.

Comment: `None` is probably a better default value than 0. Otherwise, area(0) would return "none" instead of 0, and so would area(0,0).

Comment: I presume you are aware that cubing a number would be `a**3`, not `a**2`...?

Comment: Good point! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of declaring the initial values of the args as `1` it is better if you declare it as `None`. Now if `b` is not given we can have a nested `if` statement so that your problem is met.

This program is attached for your reference

```
def area(a=None,b=None):

 if b is None:
    if a is None:
        return 'none'
    else:
        return a**3
 else:
    return a*b

print(area(2))
print(area(2,1))
print(area())
```

The program will print

```
4
2
none
```

just as what was required

Comment: Suggestion: Rather than `if not b:`, one should write `if b is not None:`. What happens when the user calls `area(0,0)`?

Comment: @jme Good point, But it must be `if b is None`. You are trying double negatives

Comment: Thank you! This was very useful. I thought I could skip the double if step, but it seems like the simplest way.

Comment: @L.R. You are welcome. You can skip the double if step by using short circuit evaluation of boolean operands. It is a easy topic. Do read more about [it](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I'd use python's awesome variable argument list feature and branch on it's `len`. See it in action:

```
>>> def func(*args):
...     return len(args), args
... 
>>> func(1)
(1, (1,))
>>> func(1,2,3)
(3, (1, 2, 3))
```

But in your case, I'd just use default `None` arguments and "abuse" a little symmetry:

```
>>> def area(a=None,b=None):
...     if b is None: b=a # a*a == a**2
...     return None if a is None else a*b # hackish alternative: return a and a*b
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if three arguments are passed? Here's a solution that throws an exception in that case.

```
def area(*args):
    if not args:
        return None
    elif len(args) == 1:
        return args[0]**2
    elif len(args) == 2:
        return args[0] * args[1]
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("Invalid number of arguments.")
```